# CSS Dynamically Resize Div to fit content?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a pop-down at the top of my page to resize with the browser. The text does, but the div containing it does not, so the text is cut off.

Here is my CSS:

```
.popdownbanner { position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;background:#FF0C10;color:#000000;font:normal 95% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="popdownbanner"><center>
        <h3 style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;font-size:18px">THIS IS MY TEXT THAT IS CUT OFF, but I have several lines more than I have typed here.<a href="#" title="Donate" target="_blank">Click here to help!</a></h3></center>
       </div>
```

The other CSS on the page conflicts with the h3 tag, thus the style tag in the HTML. If I can get it to resize without using any JavaScript, that is my preference.

Comment: Can you give more code snippets, and perhaps try and explain your problem a little better? I ran you code alone on a pen, and I don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Same here, I only see the text getting wrapped but the parent div resizes as expected.

Comment: My site is http://deadshotcolada.net/ and it is the banner that pops down after the page loads. On my screen size, the text fits inside of the div, but when I resize the page, only the text wraps; the div does not resize to fit the text, however, so the text becomes cut off by the rest of my page.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using absolute positioning, you should be able.to get away with removing the width and height properties and replacing them with right:0; and bottom:0; to have the same effect and should resize with the window. Its the methods that's served me well in the past, so hopefully works for you too!

Of course, this assumes you want a full-screen div, as your css suggests. Is that that case?

Comment: Like I stated in my original post, it is for a pop-down banner. The link to my page is http://deadshotcolada.net/, it is the red bar that appears at the top after the page is loaded.

Comment: OK, I understand what you are trying to achieve now. I have knocked up a quick jsfiddle on my phone along with some sample Samuel L Ipsum text:https://jsfiddle.net/pxvqc4d5/ and moving from portrait to landscape resizes fine using the CSS in the fiddle. Could it be a parent element which is set to position: relative combined with  your container's height: 100% causing unexpected results? The reason I ask is because the HTML and css posted on its own, I would expect, would render the banner the full size of the window

Comment: That should work, so I must have some conflicting CSS someplace. I will keep messing with it. Thank you for your help!